# vue router is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

http://localhost:3000/apartamentai?filter[city]=Vilnius

```
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter();
        const route = useRoute();

        console.log(router);
        console.log(route);
    
        onMounted(() => {
            console.log(router);
            console.log(route);
        });
    }
}
```

I get 4 `undefined`. What's wrong?

https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create and register the router in your app:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const router = createRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [],
});

createApp({})
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
```

as taken from here:
https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view

Comment: @keizah7 This is Vue 3; I just copied the code from the official router documentation. This is basically correct, but you of course can destructure the import to only load `createRouter`, `createWebHashHistory` and `createApp` methods respectively. And for your other questions I suggest check the router documentation